# servicestack vs template and ravendb

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, servicestack, ravendb

I'm using `servicestack` vs template and on this question
[I'm suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888838/service-stack-angularjs-with-ravendb-proper-approach) to use `Service.Interface` project as a place
where I should touch database.

Previously I used `AppHost` and it's `Configure` method
to configure `DocumentStore`.

Since I dont have `Configure` method on `Service.Interface` project
how should I configure `DocumentStore` in order to communicate
with ravendb?

Answer (score 3):

Solution is simple. Inside your service class (ServiceInteface) you should inject ravendb session

```
public class MyServices : Service{
   private readonly IDocumentSession session;
   public MyServices(IDocumentSession session){
      this.session = session;
   }

   // now use session to query data from database inside your webservice method call
   public object Any(SomeObjectReq request){
      var data = session.Query<ObjectToQuery>().ToList();
   }
```

since this project (ServiceInteface) is referenced in your web prj where AppHost lives you should put your db infrastracture (IDocumentStore) inside AppHost Configure method.

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
      var store = new DocumentStore(){
          Url = "http://",
          DefaultDatabase = "xxxxxx"
      }.Initialize();

      // register ravendb
      container.Register(store);
      container.Register(c =>c.Resolve<IDocumentStore>).OpenSession()).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
 }
```